# Machine Learning model to find weight/contribution of an object on a webpage

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I am working on webpage performance improvement. A webpage can consist of a number of objects. I know how much time it took for a page to load, and the objects present on that webpage. Unfortunately, I do not know how much time can be attributed to an individual object. 
So my data looks like this - I have enough training data and horsepower.

Page Name     /Objects on page      /Time taken to Load the page

---

P1              /O1,
                O2,
                O4,
                O8/                    2000 ms

---

P2              /O90,
                O10009,
                O1/                    3000 ms

---

Px              /O1900008,
                O2,
                O900/                   Predict

---

Based on this, is there an ML algorithm that will assign 'weight' or 'indication of heaviness' to an individual object, so that I can predict the total time to load for a page with any object combination? The number of total objects can be hundreds of thousands, so one hot encoding will not work. And I am reluctant to try feature hashing since it groups similar sounding objects together. But objects can be named anything, they cannot be grouped based on how they sound.